# @ElementCollection in the same table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

My question is very similar to [Map @ElementCollection to same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008763/map-elementcollection-to-same-table) but the answer there doesn't work since I am not using enums.

I want to map very simple entity to a single table:

```java
@Entity(name = "userteam")
public class UserTeam {
    @Id public String username;
    @ElementCollection public List<String> teams;
}
```

This should map to a table `userteam(username varchar(...), teams varchar(...))`. However Hibernate creates another table `userteam_teams` that has exactly this structure. I don't need the original table that hosts only the usernames - how can I squeeze this to single table?

**EDIT**: I had some success adding

```java
@CollectionTable(name = "userteams", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username"))
```

to the collection but besides having FK from the username to itself, given that the Id is primary key I can't add multiple rows with the same username.

Comment: This is not clear how one row from the `userteam` table should refer to the other.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. When fetching the entity through id, there should be simply `SELECT username, teams FROM userteam WHERE teams = 'foo-team'` and merge the rows into single entity.

Comment: Your case assume that the table `userteam` should have the FK to itself. Does the table `userteam` have it?

Comment: Yes, with the `@CollectionTable`. However I don't want that; in fact the only constraint I would be interested in is having each row (as a whole) unique. But that's a different issue.